# ping command not working in CentOS

Tags: linux, centos7

```
ping google.com
ping: google.com: Name or service not know
```

Above is the error i am getting when using the ping command in CentOs 7.
Please share your thoughts what might be wrong here.

Comment: `wget https://google.com` works?

Comment: No.getting unable to resolve host address 'google.com'

Comment: The output you posted in the question doesn't say much about the way `ping` works. It works fine, if you ask me. The problem is somewhere else: either a name server is not properly set or it is set but it doesn't work (is unreacheable, doesn't answer, doesn't have internet connection etc).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `nmtui` to connect network, then everything will be fine.

Comment: nmtui command takes you to activation of network, enps03/enps08.Just activate it and you will be able to ping google.com

Answer (score 3):

From the issue you are facing,I can tell that DNS is not working and your machine is not able to resolve domain name.
One way to quick fix this issue is to run below command:

```
..# dhclient
..# ping google.com
```

dhclient-command reconfigures your network settings and it might require root priviledge to execute this command.

Comment: this worked for me as well - I was also seeing "Error connecting the update server: [0] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known."

Answer (score 0):

The results of both `ping` and `wget` indicate that your computer is unable to reach a **DNS Server** in order to resolve the hostname `google.com`.  This isn't an error with `ping`, but rather a problem with the internet connection on your machine.

Comment: i think you are right its not connected to the internet.I am trying to connect to WiFi

Answer (score 0):

Try to ping the google name servers : 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4. If this works your routing and basic networking is functioning if not `https://www.networkworld.com/article/2693416/unix-networking-basics-for-the-beginner.html`

Answer (score 0):

i think that the first thing to try is

`$ ping -c 3 localhost   # -c 3 limits the number of pings to 3`

if that produces a result something like this:

```
PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.138 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.102 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.105 ms
```

then ping is installed and working in principle. if not, then the problem is either that your ether port is not active or connected (see other posts using 'nmtui' to set your port coordinates) or ping is either not installed or broken. in these latter cases i am not sure what to suggest.